# No module named lxml while requesting the url from browser/curl

Tags: php, python, curl, lxml

I have a python code which runs in my terminal and prints the result. I wrote a php code which executes the python code using exec("python example.py argument_1"). The php code also prints the result while executing it from the terminal.

But when I try to call the php from the browser (or) through a curl request, the result of the php is not being displayed. Apache error log displays the following message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Kindly look into this issue.

**Solution :**
I had conflict with the python versions

> exec("/usr/local/bin/python example.py argument_1") has resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you can print the sys.path(modules will be fond by python via those path ) for more details. you maybe develop your code in linux.
In linux, each user has different sys.path.
for example, I use **root** to run python to get sys.path in python,

```
'/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

use an other user to get sys.path in python

```
['',
 '/home/mahome/anaconda2/bin',
 '/home/mahome/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/mahome/anaconda2/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/mahome/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/mahome/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/mahome/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/mahome/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/mahome/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/mahome/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/mahome/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/mahome/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/mahome/.ipython']
```

so, you maybe use different user to execuate your code.

Comment: while calling the php file from the browser, I don't have root privileges. similarly, I am running it from the command line as an unprivileged user but in the second case I am getting the result. I am using apache in OS X.

Comment: you can print the sys.path in these two case and compare the result.  It is maybe helpful

Comment: The paths seem to be same.